# API Fetch Cross-Orgin Request

Tags: reactjs, fetch, use-effect

I am attempting to use the GitHub jobs api for a react app. I am attempting to use useEffect and fetch to retrieve the data but I am getting an error.

The error I am getting is the below:

Error 1: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://jobs.github.com/positions.json. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Error 2: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

I have looked at the documentation and I can't figure with the error is.

UseFetch.js

```
import { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";

const SearchAll = () => {

    const [jobs, SetJobs] = useState(null)

    const url = "https://jobs.github.com/positions.json";

    useEffect (() => {
        
        fetch(url)
        .then(res => {
            if (!res.ok) { 
              throw Error('could not fetch the data for that resource');
            } 
            return res.json();
          })
          .then(data => {
            SetJobs(data);
          })
    },[url])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CORS error means the server hasn't whitelisted your domain, it's a security mechanism implemented in browsers. Rightly so - the API you're attempting to access belongs to github.com. You'll have to build an HTTP server and proxy responses through it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS